# Which software selection server for an ios compatible server?

Tags: 14.04, server, postgresql, openssh, ios

I'm hoping to run an Ubuntu server which will in future be able to communicate to an iOS app. Which of these will allow me to do that?

```
[ ] OpenSSH server
[ ] DNS server
[ ] LAMP server
[ ] Mail server
[ ] PostgreSQL server
[ ] Print server
[ ] Samba file server
[ ] Tomcat Java server
[ ] Virtual Machine host
[ ] Manual package selection
```

Thanks!

EDIT: This is my first time using a server and I just want to explore and test and mess around. I'd like to have an app where you could type something into a text box, have the text go to the server, and have the server respond with another text which could be displayed on the iOS app.

Comment: What do you mean by "communicate"? Many of these servers can communicate with iOS.

Comment: I think you should add some usefull info, like what kind of connection/functionality would you expect ending with...

Comment: @dgonzalez updated it

Comment: updated it @Pilot6

Comment: This is a kind of chat service. None of these provide it. But there is a lot of chat services.

Comment: For example, you want to make a web page and open it in iOS browser?

Comment: @Pilot6 would a PostgreSQL database be compatible with an iOS app? Would the app be able to request a "high score" and receive a number from that database?

Comment: If the app can use the database then it will be compatible ;-)

Comment: All of those servers can be communicated with from an iOS app, if the app is configured to do so. The question is really too broad.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `tasksel` applications job to decide which packages you need to run an app on iOS.  Instead configure your server for what you need it to do, i.e.

- `LAMP Server` will serve PHP based Web Sites.
- `Tomcat Java Server` will serve Java Based WebSites
- `Mail Server` will handle email.

After doing this, connect your app via the internet to your server. Nothing is compatible with iOS unless you have a Mac.  Your server may "talk" to an iOS based app through a protocol, for example SSH, or Samba, in which case you would need those options. To actually develop an application, you need [XCode - Native](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ide/), or [Xamarin 3 Visual Studio Based Plugins for Windows](https://blog.xamarin.com/announcing-xamarin-3/)

See also [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) for an example of Protocol as a Service, which is what you'd need to do to use the approach you describe, plus the service is OS independent.